# Azure DevOps CI pipe failure when executing script: ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-1073741515'

Tags: cmd, pip, azure-pipelines, python-3.9

I defined an **Azure DevOps CI pipeline** that deploys a database to Azure SQL Instance. After this step a script is run to update `pip`. I am doing all this to run unit tests on the deployed database.

```
script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  displayName: 'Updating pip to latest version.'
```

This step is failing with;

> ##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '-1073741515'.

I added user defined capabilities as seen in the image below. Initially I was targeting `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64` but that didn't work.

[image]

I had to copy `Python3.9` into a directory `x64` and create a version file. So I tried including `pip` thinking that *perhaps the issue might be similar despite a different error message*.

[image]

[image]

I also made sure that `pip.exe` is on the path.

There have been issues at every stage of the CI pipeline after migrating from a Microsoft Agent to a **self-hosted agent on my local machine**, those steps produced errors which were more verbose with messages that were less obtuse. I am struggling to find any useful information on this. It is an error that appears many different contexts making it further difficult to diagnose.

Comment: File system error 1073741515, which translates to error type 0xC0000135, describes the inability of an executable program to run due to missing essential components or wrongly configured system files.

Comment: `CMD` is *working*, I can execute both 32bit and 64bit versions. Pip was installed with Python as a Visual Studio 2022RC extension and can run it inside and outside of VS. The agent is running as `network service`, perhaps it is a permissions issue? The error reads like it is `cmd` that has failed. I could test this by placing a preceding script that uses `cmd` to do something else.

Comment: A permission issue is VERY likely. Try executing pip from the commandline using runs to see if you can replicate the issue.